# pgAdmin-4 container connected to PostgreSQL server at boot

Tags: docker, pgadmin-4

I am running pgAdmin-4 as a docker container alongside my PostgreSQL deployment (in docker containers as well).
I am able to connect to the WebUI and manually add the DB server, getting access to all the needed information.

Is there any way to make the pgAdmin container automatically connected to my PostgreSQL server without the need for a manual configuration after the launch?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding postgress connections to pgadmin in docker file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64620446/adding-postgress-connections-to-pgadmin-in-docker-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can export & save the list of servers details in a JSON file and after starting your instance you import that into pgAdmin4. See [export/import servers](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/import_export_servers.html).

Then you can map the resulted JSON file in the docker as mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/container_deployment.html#mapped-files-and-directories).

Comment: Both link seems to be broken. Im trying to achieve that but bit lost. Any alternative link ?

Comment: This question has been asked again later, with several detailed answers, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64620446/adding-postgress-connections-to-pgadmin-in-docker-file