# Adding postgress connections to pgadmin in docker file

Tags: docker, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Is there a way to pre-configure pgadmin (maybe via env variables) with some server connections?

Say you have this docker-compose.yml, something like `PGADMIN_CONNECTIONS` env variable in this example? (`PGADMIN_CONNECTIONS` is probably not a valid ENV variable, it's just an ilustration)

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    hostname: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: dbuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: dbpass
      POSTGRES_DB: TEST_SM

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: pgadmin4@pgadmin.org
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin

      ??PGADMIN_CONNECTIONS: dbuser:dbpass@postgres:5432
```

Comment: https://github.com/thaJeztah/pgadmin4-docker/issues/26#issuecomment-354291987 might help you.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to define a `servers.json` file to configure connections. It's quite well documented [here](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/container_deployment.html).

The default path inside the container is `/pgadmin4/servers.json`. You could either `COPY` your own version of the `servers.json` file into a newly built image, or bind mount the file into the container when it is run.

The password cannot be passed to the pgadmin through JSON, but a file containing the password is referenced in the example below. See below for further information.

You can find an example structure for the `servers.json` file below:

```json
{
  "Servers": {
      "1": {
          "Name": "pgadmin4@pgadmin.org",
          "Group": "Servers",
          "Host": "magic_db",
          "Port": 5432,
          "MaintenanceDB": "postgres",
          "Username": "postgres",
          "PassFile": "/pgpass",
          "SSLMode": "prefer"
      }
  }
}
```

The `/pgpass` requires the following structure:

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

So for the example above it would be:

```
magic_db:5432:postgres:postgres:secretpassword
```

**Note:** Password was changed to PassFile in newer versions of pgadmin as seen [here](https://github.com/postgres/pgadmin4/blob/master/docs/en_US/import_export_servers.rst).

Comment: Its not that well documented on the pgadmin docker file because it doesn't contain the information in your answer which is actually required to get it going, like the structure of the json file. For others reading this Jay's second link on the passfile also contains a full example of all properties available for the server.json file. Thx Jay.

Comment: This seems to apply only for the default pgadmin user. These servers do not show up for other users. 

So, i tried using 'Shared' flag and its visible for all users but its not pre-populating the username and password. Each user must manually provide the Username and the PassFile again

Comment: @jayAchar, It's not working for me. Although I did the same what exactly you said

Answer (score 16):

This config works for me:

- postgres_db_data/
- pgpass
- servers.json
- docker-compose.yaml

1. create an empty dir call postgres_db_data
2. create "pgpass" with the following contents

`host.docker.internal:15432:postgres:postgres:postgres`

3. create "servers.json" with the following contents

```
{
  "Servers": {
    "1": {
      "Name": "docker_postgres",
      "Group": "docker_postgres_group",
      "Host": "host.docker.internal",
      "Port": 15432,
      "MaintenanceDB": "postgres",
      "Username": "postgres",
      "PassFile": "/pgpass",
      "SSLMode": "prefer"
    }
  }
}
```

4. create "docker-compose.yaml" with the following contents

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./postgres_db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
  pgadmin:
     image: dpage/pgadmin4
     restart: always
     environment:
       PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: pgadmin@pgadmin.com #the username to login to pgadmin
       PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: pgadmin # the password to login to pgadmin
     ports:
       - "5050:80"
     volumes:
       - ./servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json # preconfigured servers/connections
       - ./pgpass:/pgpass # passwords for the connections in this file
     depends_on:
       - "db"
```

5. run  `docker compose up`
6. open http://localhost:5050/browser/

Comment: I get `fe_sendauth: no password supplied` when trying to open the server in pgadmin interface. From what I read it could be because of permissions of the pgpass file but as I am on Windows, I don't know how to fix this

Comment: Please take a look at  my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66578506/where-is-the-pgpass-file-in-pgadmin4-docker-container-when-this-file-is-mounted/69258794#69258794

Comment: @LincolnD Your answer is very helpful! Only thing I needed to [change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76823892/4695280) here is volume for `.pgpass`. Also I changed database name in this file from `postgres` to `*` to be able to affect other databases too.

Answer (score 11):

### To avoid typing any login/connection info/passwords in the UI

This is a single self-contained docker-compose file. You don't need to create any other files.

**NOTE**: Requires [Docker Compose version 2.23.1](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/v2.23.1) or later *(for the inline config support that was added in [Compose Specification 1.20.1](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/releases/tag/v1.20.1))*

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:16.1
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:2023-11-20-2
    ports:
      - 8082:80
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=postgres@example.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=postgres
      - PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE=False
      - PGADMIN_CONFIG_MASTER_PASSWORD_REQUIRED=False
    entrypoint: /bin/sh -c "chmod 600 /pgpass; /entrypoint.sh;"
    user: root
    configs:
      - source: servers.json
        target: /pgadmin4/servers.json
      - source: pgpass
        target: /pgpass

configs:
  pgpass:
    content: db:5432:*:postgres:postgres
  servers.json:
    content: |
      {"Servers": {"1": {
        "Group": "Servers",
        "Name": "My Local Postgres 16.1",
        "Host": "db",
        "Port": 5432,
        "MaintenanceDB": "postgres",
        "Username": "postgres",
        "PassFile": "/pgpass",
        "SSLMode": "prefer"
      }}}
```

- `PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE=False` disables the pgadmin4 login screen.
- `PGADMIN_CONFIG_MASTER_PASSWORD_REQUIRED=False` removes the need to enter the master password when the login screen is disabled.
- Doesn't use `host.docker.internal`, which means it works on Linux out of the box.
- Fixes the `fe_sendauth: no password supplied`-error in previous examples where you need to manually enter your postgres password the first time.

Comment: I am getting `chmod: /pgpass: Operation not permitted` when running the entrypoint of pgadmin config. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @Rasto: What platform are you running on? And which version of docker/docker-compose?