# fe_sendauth: no password supplied error when using passfile in pgadmin with docker-compose on windows?

Tags: docker-compose, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64620446/6165833) and other resources, I was able to set a default server connection in pgadmin with the `servers.json` config file.

But when I try to open the server connection I get this error and the password is asked:

> fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Without the passfile, I don't have the error (but obviously the password is asked too).

---

On my windows filesystem I have:
*../db/servers.json*
*../db/servers_pass*

With the following pass file:

```
#host:port:db:user:pass
database:5432:*:postgres:mypasswd
```

I first tried with a simpler passfile with only `database:5432:postgres:mypasswd:postgres:mypasswd` and no newline, no comment. I had the same error.

`database` is the name of the docker-compose image for Postgres and the name of the host (the servers.json is working and the connection to that host is fine, except for the password).

---

Those files are mounted in the docker compose to `/pgadmin4/`

```
volumes:
    - ../db/servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json
    - ../db/servers_pass:/pgadmin4/servers_pass
```

I can see them in the docker container

```
-rwxr-xr-x    1 pgadmin  pgadmin        526 Nov 18 10:22 servers.json
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            57 Nov 18 11:06 servers_pass
```

It's a bit weird that they do not have the same owner.
I also read on other questions that permissions of the passfile needs to be 600 but how can I change that when the files are actually on the Windows filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it the same problem, but, in server mode (used with containers) the PassFile path is prefixed with the storage dir.

So, if you set your PassFile to /foo/pass, pgadmin will look for it in `/var/lib/pgadmin/storage/your_user_email/foo/pass`

I have created a report [here](https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/7134)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html), `.pgpass` file (note the dot in the name):

1) should be located in home directory (in my case it is `/home/pgadmin`; you can check yours via `eval echo ~$USER` command in pgadmin's container). So volume looks like that:

```
`- ../db/servers_pass:/home/pgadmin/.pgpass`
```

2) as you correctly noticed, should have `0600` permissions. I work in Ubuntu, but what I've done is run `chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass` directly in the container. Because this file is a volume, container's file permissions overwrote permissions of the appropriate volume's file on the host.

After doing these steps problem disappeared.

Comment: This works, but the problem is that you can't set chmod 0600 on that file from compose.yaml (insufficient permissions)

Comment: @Andrey I do it in the entrypoint script.